# SetCallBack only firing after user action and not automatically

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, community

I am building a community containing lightning components.

I have a lightning component controller calling a function in the helper.
The helper function calls the apex controller function to retrieve a URL.
When retrieved, inside setcallback, this URL is opened in a new tab.

Issue is the following: setcallback function is not executing by itself.
It only executes when I open the community menu. Why does it only execute when I click on the community menu and not automatically?

What am I missing exactly?

Controller:

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var appID = helper.getParameterByName("AppId");

    var paid = component.get("v.paid");
    if(appID != undefined && !paid){
        var get3dsURLInterval =  setInterval(function(){ 
            var pf3dsURL = component.get("v.payfort3dsURL"); 
            //alert(pf3dsURL);
            if(pf3dsURL == null || pf3dsURL == undefined || pf3dsURL == ''){

                helper.get3dsURL(component);
            }
        }, 10000); //use local storage and tab selection to see if call get3dsurl is needed
        component.set("v.get3dsURLInterval", get3dsURLInterval) ;  
    }

},
```

Helper:

```
    get3dsURL:function(component){
    var appID = this.getParameterByName("AppId");
    //alert(appID);
    var action = component.get("c.pf3dsURL");
    action.setParams({
        "appID": appID,  
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(p){
        var state = p.getState();

        if (state === 'SUCCESS')
        {
            var response = p.getReturnValue();
            console.log("3dsUrl is: ");
            console.log(response);          
            //var encodedURL = encodeURI(response); 
            if(response != null && response != undefined && response != ''){

                clearInterval(component.get("v.get3dsURLInterval"));
                component.set("v.payfort3dsURL",response);

                var executed = component.get("v.payfort3dsUrlExecuted");

                if(!executed){

                    component.set("v.payfort3dsUrlExecuted", true);
                    var eUrl= $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");                   
                    eUrl.setParams({                        
                        //"url": encodedURL     
                        "url": response                  
                    });                    
                    eUrl.fire();                                                
                }          
            }             
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);

},  

getParameterByName : function(name, url)
{    
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"), results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));        
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When firing an Aura event, you have to be within the Aura life cycle, otherwise the event won't dispatch until the next time you are. In order to fix the problem, you need to wrap the callback inside [$A.getCallback](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_mod_ext_js.htm):

```
    var get3dsURLInterval =  setInterval($A.getCallback(function(){ 
        var pf3dsURL = component.get("v.payfort3dsURL"); 
        //alert(pf3dsURL);
        if(pf3dsURL == null || pf3dsURL == undefined || pf3dsURL == ''){

            helper.get3dsURL(component);
        }
    }), 10000); //use local storage and tab selection to see if call get3dsurl is needed
```

As an aside, you can write a much more compact URL query string parser (assuming you don't need IE 11 support):

```
getParameterByName: function(name, url) {
  return (url?new URL(url): window.location).searchParams.get(name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!!  You're the best